# Network Drops when Transferring Many Files

Tags: networking

I'm having an odd problem. I have a 2 PCs, both are using wired ethernet. I have a drive on PC A connected as a network drive on PC B. When I use that drive to transfer a large amount (I'd estimate around 20GB+) then after some time, the network on PC B will disconnect. The entire network is disconnected, I have no internet or anything. Only way to get it back is to restart. Anything I can check to see what the issue is?

PC A is directly connected to the main router.

PC B connects to another router which is just acting as a switch/AP, that connects to the main router.

Comment: I once had a computer where old drivers led to the same thing - though it was the WiFi-adapter. Have you tried to update drivers, have you tried to change the way the computers are connected? Which OS are we talking about?

Comment: I'll take a look at updating drivers. Both are running Win 10. I'll also try connecting them both directly to the router.